# Laravel Eloquent retrieve specific information

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have just started using Laravel Eloquent and stuck at retrieving some data. It would be great if someone can guide me.

I have two tables (not mentioning user table)

**Institutes**:

```
 id    |name   | user_id 

 1     |abc    |22       
 2     |xyz    |32
```

Now institute2 (xyz) has following programs

**Programs**:

```
 id     |institute_id| name | admission_open|

  1     | 2          |exp1  | 1             |
  2     | 2          |exp2  | 0             |
```

Institute.php

```
class Institute extends Eloquent
{
  protected  $table = 'institutes';

  public function programs(){
    return $this->hasMany('Program');
   }

}
```

Program.php

```
class Program extends Eloquent
{
   protected  $table = 'programs';

   public function institute()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo('Institute');
   }
}
```

What I want:

I want to get name of institutes for which admissions (admission_open =1) are open in programs table.

How should I write query for that.do I have to join tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tests = Programs::where('admission','1')->get();
```

Now after you get object you can loop

```
 foreach($tests as $test) {
$test->institute->name;
}
```

Comment: $tests returning data fine. but `$test->institute->name;`  throwing error ` Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: this means u havent set the foregin keey where is ur migration

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Like user @ujwal dhakal said or with joins, but I prefer this:

```
Institute:::whereHas('program', function($query) {
    $query->where('admission', '=',1);
})->get();
```

Comment: getting error `call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::program()`

Comment: ok i tried this one and getting empty array `[]`: ` $list =Institute::whereHas('programs', function($query) {
                $query->where('admission_open', '=',1);
            })->get();
            echo json_encode($list );`

Comment: @Nomi can You provide a dump of database? For example store it to the pastebin.com ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$programs = Program::where('admission_open','1')->with('institute')->get();
```

OR

```
$programs = Program::where('admission_open','=','1')->with('institute')->get();
```

$programs will have Program objects with admission_open = 1 and institute data

```
foreach($programs as $program){
       echo $program->institute->name;
}
```

Comment: In both cases I am getting null value for institute Here is my json `[{"id":237,"name":"BS Software","admission_open":1,"created_at":"2016-03-08 18:06:39","updated_at":"2016-03-08 18:06:39","institute_id":21,"institute":null}`

Comment: do you have any data in table for id 21 in institute table :: this id I can see in your output

Comment: thanks  problem is solved. I had problems with database relations.

Answer (score 0):

```
$institutions = Institute:::whereHas('programs', function($query) {
                   $query->where('admission_open', '=',1);
                })->get();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: getting empty array `[]`